# PHP file_get_contents returns 404 on image download

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle

I am trying to download images using the PHP function `file_get_contents()` but on some images the server returns a 404 error. I sent `User-Agent Slow Down` but the results were the same.

Can someone here help? Below is the code for testing images:

```
<?php 

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$imageDir = "https://mangatx.com/manga/the-return-of-the-crazy-demon/chapter-2/";


$HttpClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $HttpClient->request('GET', $imageDir);
$html = '' . $response->getBody();
$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$chapterImages = $crawler->filter('.reading-content img')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
    $imageRes = trim($node->attr("data-src"));
    $imageRes = str_replace('https://', '', $imageRes);
    $imageRes = str_replace('http://', '', $imageRes);
    $imageRes = str_replace('//', '', $imageRes);
    $imageRes = str_replace('http:', '', $imageRes);

    return trim("https://{$imageRes}");
});

// print_r($chapterImages);

function get_contents($value){
    // Create a stream
    $opts = [
        "http" => [
            "method" => "GET",
            "header" => "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
        ]
    ];

    // DOCS: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    file_get_contents($value, false, $context);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($http_response_header);
    echo "</pre>";
}

foreach($chapterImages as $value){
    sleep(1);
    get_contents($value);
    sleep(1);
}

?>
```

If You want access to all files here is the google drive link [Files Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z2wDEb_MzTn1eVfGjMZ1Bz3w82tA9fax/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is it consistently the same images? Do they have anything in common? What have you done to isolate why some images work and others fail?

Comment: Maybe the website has a protection against scripts. « I sent `User-Agent Slow Down` », it should look like the user agent of a browser, this one doesn't.

Comment: Seems that website is protected by cloudflare. They might have setup crawler protection.

Comment: No crawler protection, when i use different User-Agent It works seems like, there are some headers missing, i have a java app that bypasses it just easily but i don't know how to read java code

Comment: the error comes when trying on the optimized images it seems like they use plugin that cache images and blocks requests and sends cookie expired header when i change user-agent again it's fine but that solution can't last